# Gitlab External IP on a local network

Tags: gitlab

I have recently installed Gitlab on an internal server (192.168.0.XX). After installation I edit the Gitlab.rb file external_ip: 192.168.0.XX and I run the reconfigure file. However when I go to the address on the server I am not served with the Gitlab page. Am I doing something silly?

Comment: Assuming you can ping to the server, can you try navigating to http://192.168.0.XX/users/sign_in? I faced similar issues where the admin setting of Home Page URL was causing an issue.

Comment: Yeh I can ping it just fine. I have Apache running on it too and get back the info page when I visit the server on browser.

Comment: Never mind. Apache was causing the problem... Thanks for your help.

Comment: probably a port conflict then. Try setting some random port # like 1111 in gitlab.rb file and then navigate to 192.168.0.XX:1111/

Answer (score 1):

Don't be an idiot and have Apache running at the same time...